# How to Bake down all data to a single object

Tags: animation, camera, transforms, baking, tracking

Can anyone please suggest how can I bake all the data into a single camera object?
I have exported a camera track from 3dequalizer. When I import it inside blender this is the structure that I get.

[image]

The parent object 3DE4Scene has some translation data. The camera object has animation keys.
I want to create a new camera and bake down all this information into that camera. So eventually I will only have a single camera object with all the translation and animation information.

Answer (score 0):

Try Selecting all objects and then pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. It should join them.

Comment: did you mean `ctrl+j`?